# Can a Function wrap a Class and know when the last method is called?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am trying to write a Function which wraps a Class to tidy up the some syntax.

However, I want the Function to always return a specific string after the last method. I have prepared a jsfiddle below. Basically...

```js
Class DoMath() {
  // ...do things

  get answer() {
    return this.result
  }
}

function doMathWrapper(...args) {
  return new DoMath(...args)
}
```

I want a function to wrap this Class and return as if `.answer` is automatically appended to the last method call in a chain.

But instead the Class just returns `this` and you get the entire object, which is necessary to keep chaining.

**Currently**

- `doMathWrapper(1).add(2)` returns `{ answer: 3 }`
- `doMathWrapper(1).add(2).answer` returns `3`, but having to append `.answer` every time you use the function is annoying

**Ideally** the function just returns `answer` after the last method:

- `doMathWrapper(1).add(2).add(2)` would return `5`
- `doMathWrapper(1).add(2)` would return `3`
- `doMathWrapper(1)` would return `1`

...is this even possible?

More complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/simeonGriggs/jq5401w2/26/

Comment: How's the `add` function defined? Look like `add` is returning `this` when it should return `this.answer`

Comment: If you see in the jsfiddle link, `.add` has to return `this` to continue method chaining. If it returns `this.answer`, no more methods can run.

Comment: `doMathWrapper` can either return `this` or the `answer`. It can't return both.

Comment: Yeah I think what you want is not possible. If you want to keep the chaining and get the number as the final value you'd always need a final method like `answer()` or `result()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally the function just returns answer after the last method:
>
> - doMathWrapper(1).add(2) would return 3
> - doMathWrapper(1) would return 1
>
> ...is this even possible?

No, it is not possible. When `doMathWrapper(1)` is called, it's impossible to predict whether someone will eventually call `.add(2)` later on. By writing it on a single line it looks like they're pretty tightly related, but they're evaluated one at a time, without knowing about eachother. To highlight this, note that it could be split onto two lines:

```
const temp = doMathWrapper(1);
temp.add(2);
```

...or separated in time:

```
const temp = doMathWrapper(1);
setTimeout(() => {
  temp.add(2);
}, 10000);
```

... or happen unpredictably:

```
const temp = doMathWrapper(1);
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  temp.add(2);
}
```

All you know is that `doMathWrapper(1)` is currently being called, and you need to decide right now what you want to return. You can either return an object with a `.add` method, or you can return the number 1; you can't do both.

---

For some cases, it might work to return an object with a `.add` method and also a `.valueOf` method, with the value of method being a way to get `1` automatically. [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) gets called automatically for certain operations, such as when you try to do addition with an object:

```
const temp = doMathWrapper(1);
console.log(3 + temp); // 4
```

But for a more general case, you'll need to be explicit that you want to get the result out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ... even if I'm a bit disappointed! I guess in my use-case I don't ever actually want the function to be "live" like you can add too later. I just like the syntax look of the method chaining but want to only ever return a string – not the class object.